# split input data and have one array output

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to split an input data to an numpy array but I got a separated 3 elements in array not as one array with all elements as the following:

```
import numpy as np
with open('dataa.dat', 'r') as f:
     input_data = f.readlines()
     input_data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in input_data]

     t_f = input_data[0].split("-",2)
     t_f2 = []
     for elt in t_f:
         if "*" in elt:
             n, mult = elt.split("*")
             t_f2 = t_f2 + [int(n)] * int(mult)
        else:
            t_f2.append(elt)
    c_w = np.array(t_f2)
    print('kk',c_w) # To be like this: [1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected and actual output?

Comment: @12944qwerty
Actual output is:
 ['1,1,1' '1,2,1' '1' '1' '1']
But I would like to have a normal numpy array 
[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]

Comment: Could you provide an example input line from the `data.dat` file?

Comment: @taxevader
1,1,1-1,2,1-1*3

Comment: @msci is that the only line in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to split the numbers separated by the commas. You can do that by replacing the line

```
t_f2.append(elt)
```

with

```
t_f2 += [int(x) for x in elt.split(',')]
```

```
import numpy as np
with open('dataa.dat', 'r') as f:
    input_data = f.readlines()
    input_data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in input_data]

    t_f = input_data[0].split("-",2)
    t_f2 = []
    for elt in t_f:
        if "*" in elt:
            n, mult = elt.split("*")
            t_f2 = t_f2 + [int(n)] * int(mult)
        else:
            t_f2 += [int(x) for x in elt.split(',')]
    c_w = np.array(t_f2)
    print('kk',c_w) # To be like this: [1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1]
```